# Combining JOINs with OR

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-like

I'm not sure how I can optimize this. I need to select from a table, applying a keyword search to multiple columns in various tables:

```
SELECT  mt.Id
FROM    tbl_MyTable mt
JOIN    tbl_AnotherTable at
ON      mt.ForeignKey = at.Id
WHERE   <some stuff>
        AND (
            mt.Id IN (
                SELECT  mt2.Id
                FROM    tbl_MyTable mt2
                JOIN    @keywordLike kl
                ON      mt2.Name LIKE kl.Keyword
                WHERE   <same stuff as before, but for mt2>
            ) OR
            at.Id IN (
                SELECT  at2.Id
                FROM    tbl_AnotherTable at2
                JOIN    @keywordLike kl
                ON      at2.Name LIKE kl.Keyword
                        OR at2.Widget LIKE kl.Keyword
            ) -- in reality, the "keyword" search is applied to three other tables
        )
```

`@keywordLike` is a table variable containing strings to attempt to match against multiple columns in multiple tables.

Note that the `Id` from `tbl_MyTable` will be returned any time *anything* matches the keyword search, not *all*, which is why I'm not just doing a bunch of `JOIN`s. These tables are very large, and the `<some stuff>` parts I skipped over is filtering out quite a bit. It seems what I really want is to be able to `JOIN...ON...`, but with an `OR` between them, but this is the best alternative I've thought of so far.

Here's some sample data:

```
[[MyTable]]
Id      Name    ForeignKey
 1      Alice            1
 2      Bob              2

[[AnotherTable]]
Id      Name     Widget
 1      iPhone   Screen
 2      Android  Screen
```

If `@keywordLike` contained just the following string: `%A%`, we'd return:

- `1` (because `%A%` matches `Alice`)
- `2` (because `%A%` matches `Android`, and Bob's `ForeignKey` matches that Id

If `@keywordLike` contained `%Alice%`, `iPhone`, we'd return:

- `1` (because `%Alice%` matches `Alice`)
- `1` (because `%iPhone%` matches `iPhone` and Alice's `ForeignKey` matches that Id

If `@keywordLike` contained `Screen` we'd return:

- `1`
- `2`

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Explain the logic -- sample data and desired results help.

Comment:  Let me know if that sample data isn't helpful, I'll expand it.

Comment: Firstly, `JOIN @keywordLike` is not valid syntax - please post code that won't throw an error. The next thing I suggest is to replace all of your `IN (` with `WHERE EXISTS (`

Comment: ... oh is `@keywordLike` a table variable? It would be helpful to indicate it. Sometimes people try to do dynamic SQL that way and without full code (i.e. variable definition) I'd prefer not to assume anything.

Comment: Sorry, yes, `@keywordLike` is a table variable. In my original code, the passed-in keywords are preprocessed into it. I'll make that clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this query do what you want?

```
SELECT mt.Id
FROM tbl_MyTable mt JOIN
     tbl_AnotherTable at
     ON mt.ForeignKey = at.Id
WHERE mt.name LIKE @keywordlike OR
      at.name LIKE @keywordlike OR
      at.widget LIKE @keywordlike;
```

If so, this will be challenging to make more efficient in SQL Server.  One possibility is full text search, but even t that can be tricky across tables.

EDIT:

If `@keywordlike` is a table variable:

```
SELECT mt.Id
FROM tbl_MyTable mt JOIN
     tbl_AnotherTable at
     ON mt.ForeignKey = at.Id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @keywordlike kl WHERE mt.name LIKE kl.keyword) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @keywordlike kl WHERE at.name LIKE kl.keyword) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @keywordlike kl WHERE at.widget LIKE kl.keyword);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't indicate that `@keywordLike` was a table variable.

Comment: Hmm.. Is there any reason to do the `SELECT 1` _n_ times? Isn't that the same as `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @keywordLike kl WHERE (mt.name LIKE kl.keyword OR at.name LIKE kl.keyword OR ...)`?

Comment: @moswald . . . No, there is no reason.  I just followed the same structure as the first answer.  If you had an equality comparison, `or` could make it harder for the optimizer to user indexes, but that is not an issue here.